# What kind of load can an aluminium split batten system support

Tags: walls, load-bearing

I am looking at ways to attach a large (2.4m) and heavy (25kg) bookshelf to a wall.

The bookshelf has two tiers. Assuming books weigh about 30kg per metre, when full this bookshelf might weigh 169kg.

Is an aluminium split batten system strong enough to maintain this kind of weight if it is screwed into a stud wall?

In the past I have had it supported from below with 4 braces that could bear 30kg each, but I like the out of sight aspect of the split batten.

For reference this is the kind of system that I am looking at, but I haven't seen any specific information about what kind of weight they can bear.

https://alltradealuminium.com.au/product/split-batten/

Comment: I don't see how this can be answered by anyone but the manufacturer.  You might contact them and ask.  It's quite possible they have an engineering document that has design details beyond that shown on the site you referenced.

Comment: It would depend on what the French cleats are attached to and how far from the wall the load is. If you have a deep shelf with load toward the front edge, the levering force is going to be greater than with a shallow shelf. However, French cleats are known for being _very_ strong. If I were to guess, you wouldn't have a problem with your 170Kg load. However, that really is just a _guess_.